# How can I determine the minimum NSRect for drawing an attributed string?

Tags: cocoa, drawrect, nsattributedstring, nsrect

I cannot seem to find this and hope it is a FAQ somewhere.
How can I get the minimum NSRect needed to draw an NSAttributed string on OS X?
I am doing an overlay borderless window, but I want to constrain the size based on what is needed to display the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use NSTextContainer and NSLayoutManager.
More from Apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextLayout/Tasks/StringHeight.html

Comment: This is in fact what I ended up doing and the same reference I used.